# Accessing listview itemtemplate from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, itemtemplate

I'm hoping to dynamically change the number of columns in my ItemTemplate of my ListView:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ReportListView" DataSourceID="ReportListViewSDS">
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
       </tr>
   </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
       <!-- need to dynamically create the number of columns in the code behind 
            based on the select statement in the SelectCommand -->
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then in the code behind I've got:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Based on The Request.Form variables sent, the SQL command will 
    ' select x number of columns:
    ' SqlStatement = "SELECT " for each Request.Form values " FROM staff"
    '      example: "SELECT Fname, Lname, email, phone FROM staff"
    ' Run sql command.

    ' that all works, the question now is how do i change the ItemTemplate 
    ' so that it has the correct number of columns.  Something like this: (pseudo code)
    For each row found in sql command
       ReportListView.ItemTemplate.Add( "<tr>" )
       For each Request.Form as i
            ReportLIstView.ItemTemplate.Add( "<td>" & sqlresult(i) & "</td>" )
       Next
       ReportListView.ItemTemplate.Add( "</tr>" )
    Next
 End Sub
```

Maybe there's another way to go about it, but that's the only idea of got so far.  asp.net newbie, any advise, very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of the answers I recieved this is what I got to work:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ReportListView" DataSourceID="ReportListViewSDS">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
       </tr>
   </table>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

 ' Based on The Request.Form variables sent, the SQL command will 
 ' select x number of columns:
 ' SqlStatement = "SELECT " for each Request.Form values " FROM staff"
 '      example: "SELECT Fname, Lname, email, phone FROM staff"
 ' Run sql command.

 ' this seems to actually run the sql, and bind the results.  If i don't run the function DataBind(), it's as if the sql never runs.
 ReportListView.DataBind() 

 ' the rest of the work is done in the next function.
End Sub

Protected Sub ReportListView_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ReportListView.ItemDataBound

    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem) Then
        Dim plc As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("itemPlaceHolder"), PlaceHolder)
        Dim di As Data.DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem()

        For Each c In di.Row.ItemArray
            Dim l As New Literal
            l.Text = String.Format("<td class='customreport'>{0}</td>", c.ToString)
            plc.Controls.Add(l)
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks much for the direction of the other 2 answers, that definately got me 90%, just a couple other tweaks and i was good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to have to do this a little differently. Try something like this:

```
<table>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
               <asp:PlaceHolder Id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</table>
```

The syntax might not be perfect, but try doing something like this in your code behind:

```
For Each listItem As ListViewDataItem In ListView1.Items
    Dim plc As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(listItem.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder)
    If plc IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item As String In Request.Form
            plc.Controls.Add(New Literal(String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", item)))
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Great ideas, implemented it, but getting an error on this: plc.Controls.Add(New Literal(String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", item))).  Error is "Too many arguments to public sub new()".  Not familiar with Literal, and how it's being used here, any advise?

Comment: FYI:  Since plc.Controls.Add takes and object i tried this:  
   Dim tb As New TableCell()
   tb.Text = "<td>Hello</td>"
   plc.Controls.Add(tb)

That doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't appear the "<td>Hello</td>" is being added to each row of the listview. :(

Comment: I got this working.  Had to add ListView.DataBind() before the for each loop.  Now the issue is the For Each Item As String In Request.Form, I actually need it to go through each column returned from the sql, because I will be putting the returned values from the sql command in the plc.Control.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: That is actually the point of using the ItemDataBound event.  Each time the listView binds a row of data, this event is fired with the event arguments containing the row of data being bound.  So you could combine the other answer with this one and have both column headers and the values retrieved from each row.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to set up the ItemTemplate the same way but since you are using a databound control you might want to take advantage of the DataBound event of the listview.  This syntax may not be perfect because you may be using a different collection to bind to the list (which would be done after query execution) but this should get you on the right track:

```
Protected Sub ReportListView_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ReportListView.ItemDataBound
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem) Then
        Dim di As Data.DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
        Dim plc As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder)

        For Each c In di.Row.ItemArray
            Dim l As New Literal
            l.Text = String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", c.ToString)
            plc.Controls.Add(l)
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

I would typically use a Repeater for this type of work since it is bare-bones and lightweight.  You really aren't taking advantage of any of the listview features from what i see.

Comment: Code looks great,  implemented it.  Got error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in reference to this line: plc.Controls.Add(l).  Played with it a little, can't seem to asp.net to realize that 'l' is not a null object.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: btw, I'm using a listview because I want to be able to sort the list, and I'm not familiar with the Repeater.  I will look into that,  thanks!

Comment: I made an edit to the code... Sorry about that.  In the FindControl line it should have read:  e.Item.FindControl rather than ListViewItem.FindControl

Answer (score 1):

i use this code to hide a element in the item template

```
visible='<%# Eval("Abstract").ToString().Length == 0 ? false : true %>'
```